# Allow partial answers for "too localized" questions

Tags: discussion, answers, too-localized

I'm taking this question as an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836864/code-after-foreach-is-not-executing

This question contains a general description of what OP thinks is the problem (`foreach` interrupts execution) and a dump of his whole code.

It's a "pls fix my code" post with a real question appended.

I answered the "real" question part in an answer ("no, foreach does not interrupt your code; either you or a fatal error does that") and commented the question telling the user to isolate the problem better.

In other words, I didn't answer his localized question, but I answered the question that could theoretically be valid (altough simple).

My answer got deleted, and judging by the faq, it got deleted because it was partial (it didn't answer the localized question) . Or it got deleted by a vigilante that wanted to "punish" the newbie for asking such a localized question.

Should we really just ignore and downvote localized questions that **contain** a genuine question?

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145108/should-i-refrain-from-answering-a-question-if-it-is-too-localized?rq=1

Comment: I'm not seeing an additional general case question in addition to the localized "plz fix my codez" question.  I see nothing about a foreach being interrupted or not being run to completion.  Perhaps you misread the question?

Comment: @Servy Well, the question's title is "Code after foreach is not executing" and there is the part about "After completion of that process [the foreach] i should get a alert message like Inserted successfully..!!." Implying that he doesn't get his alert

Comment: @Roman I don't see that as an answerable question on it's own, nor does that have anything to do with a foreach loop.  The only question there, without the example, is "why would a given line of code not be executed" for which there are a huge number of answers, none of which are really helpful to anyone without further information.  Such a question would be "Not a real question".

Comment: @Servy ok. It's just that I could imagine someone typing into google "code after foreach is not executing" and I'd like to give them an answer that says "That is probably not really your problem" and don't let them create another new "too localized" question because they didn't find this one.

Answer (score 3):

Edit the question to remove the "too localized" content and leave the genuine question. Be bold.

Comment: I will be happy to see this in comment section.

Comment: While I'd agree with this answer in general; in this specific case I'm not seeing a general question outside of the localized one, so I see no option but to close it as too localized.

Comment: @Servy I agree with you in this particular case. I think someone could infer a real question from what's being asked, but there isn't one explicitly asked. I frequently see people ask a real question, then include all their "too localized" code to show what they have so far and why they *think* it's not working.

Comment: @Byte56 Yes, as I said, this *can* be the proper solution to the situation the OP described, it just doesn't seem to be the case for his example.  I went to the question and tried to refactor it to a generalized question rather than a localized one; I see no way of doing that.

Comment: By the way welcome to [meta], Jon Skeet of [gamedev.se]! :P

Comment: Thanks! I figured I wasn't spending enough time on stack exchange :p